# Using 12V to power a laptop which PSU is rated at 19V

Tags: laptop

I have laptop with a (dead)battery rated at 11.1V and a Power supply rated at 19V.

I also have a 3s battery pack made with 18650 Li-ion batteries, meaning 11.1V nominal.

Can I power my laptop directly (trough the DC connector) with the battery pack without the need of a boost converter? What are the downsides?

Comment: You need to know more around the circuits behind the power input plug . For example if it starts with a step-down to lower than 11volts  for example then it could be OK.   But standard for moderns laptops are all around 19v.  So I guess no , you cannot use that 3s battery.

Comment: You can't power it with 11.1V through the DC jack, but you _might_ be able to power it through the 'dead' battery. You could open up the dead battery, remove the cells, and wire in a connection to your external battery. I did this with an old IBM Thinkpad to power it from a 12V car battery.

Answer (score 2):

No. The laptop expects 19V. If, and only if, the laptop itself (not the battery pack or charger) is marked that it accepts an input range that includes 11V, then you can use your battery pack to run the laptop.